SwiperJS React - Dynamic widths, with center/active element having a larger width?
I designed a slider for our website and coded it in JS to show how it should look. However the developers are struggling to get this to work in SwiperJS React.

centerered
auto-width (since the active element is 2x)
gap must be the same, and not have the active element overlap the other slides (so active slide pushed out the others, not overlap it, so transform: scale() can't be used.

We tried to use onSlideChange, and then calling Update(), otherwise the active slide has a 2x width, but the centre position isn't calculated correctly and it's off-center. When we add this update(), it destroys the transition and the slider just immediately "jumps" to the new slide, without scrolling smoothing, whilst animating the widths (which is CSS).
I was able to code it myself in just plain JS with my limited abilities (ok, it's not responsive, touch, drag, etc.) but it works like I want it to. Is this even possible in SwiperJS?
Maybe there is another way to animate the width enlarge and request the slider to update the sizes without breaking the smooth transition?
Tried all the options and also tried various methods and still couldn't find the right combination. Maybe you need to write a custom plugin. Not sure the devs have those skills.
Here is the codepen:
https://codepen.io/brandbrilliance/full/QWXgqjw
Javascript
var active = 1;
var slider = document.querySelector("#slider");
var arrowprev = document.querySelector("#arrow-prev");
var arrownext = document.querySelector("#arrow-next");
var wrapper = document.querySelector("#slider-wrapper");
var slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");

//setup events
arrowprev.addEventListener("click", updateSlider);
arrowprev.addEventListener("touchstart", mobileClick);
arrownext.addEventListener("click", updateSlider);
arrownext.addEventListener("touchstart", mobileClick);

function mobileClick(event) { event.currentTarget.id.click(event); }

//first
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", firstSlider);

function firstSlider(event) {
    var curslide = document.getElementById("slide-01")
    var newslide = document.getElementById("slide-02");

    //scroll
    var slidercenter = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2;
    var slidelarge = curslide.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    var slidesmall = newslide.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    var slidegap = parseInt( window.getComputedStyle( wrapper ).getPropertyValue('row-gap') );
    var wrapperpos = (slidesmall * active) + (slidegap * (active-1));

    wrapper.style.left = ( slidercenter - wrapperpos ) + "px";
}

function updateSlider(event) {
    //console.log(slides.length);
    console.log(event.currentTarget.id);

    var newactive = active;
    var checkarrow = event.currentTarget.id
    if (checkarrow == "arrow-prev")
                 newactive--;
    if (checkarrow == "arrow-next")
                newactive++;

    if (newactive < 1)
            newactive = 1;
    if (newactive > slides.length)
            newactive = slides.length;
    //console.log(newactive);
    //remove old class
    if (newactive != active) {
        var curslide = document.getElementById("slide-0"+active)
        curslide.classList.remove("active");
        
        var newslide = document.getElementById("slide-0"+newactive);
        newslide.classList.add("active")
        first = false;
        active = newactive;
    
        //scroll
        var slidercenter = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2;
        var slidelarge = curslide.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        var slidesmall = newslide.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        var slidegap = parseInt( window.getComputedStyle( wrapper ).getPropertyValue('row-gap') );
        var wrapperpos = (slidesmall * active) + (slidegap * (active-1));

        //console.log(slidercenter);
        //console.log(slidegap);
        //console.log(newslide.offsetLeft);
        
        wrapper.style.left = ( slidercenter - wrapperpos ) + "px";
    }
}

